# PHP Parsing Getting the latest value from a string using a delimiter

Tags: php

I have a question which relates to PHP. Is there any way to just grab the last string using a delimiter?
For example, to put you in perspective, I want to grab the lastest content from the `/`  from every string.

```
/folder1/blabla/important
/folder2/blabla/blabla/bla/important2
```

How could I using PHP cut the whole string and get only the latest value. The output would be something like:

```
/important
/important2
```

I have tried regex but I am not very good at it,

MY CODE:

```
$var = 'goldfe/sfksfksk/admadmadmam/akdmasdkasm/red';
echo $var . '<br>';
$varPretty = explode('/', $var);
echo $varPretty[-1];
```

Here the `$varPretty[-1]` should return `red`.

- ANOTHER SOLUTION IS:

```
$var = 'goldfe/sfksfksk/admadmadmam/akdmasdkasm/red';
echo $var . '<br>';
$varPretty = explode('/', $var);
echo end($varPretty);
```

Comment: Several potential solutions. Explode and take last element. Find position of last slash and extract substring from there to end of string. Regex (which you mentioned). Either way, please post your own efforts when asking a question - if someone can identify where you went wrong with your logic, you can potentially learn more than from simply receiving a working solution.

Comment: Thanks @El_Vanja If I get something out of this I will update the post for the community. :)

Comment: Updated with my code, so now I can help others too @El_Vanja

Comment: Note that you can't access the last element of the array with a negative index. You can use the [`end()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) function there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this method will work for you:

```
$txt = "/folder1/blabla/important";
echo substr($txt, strrpos($txt, '/') + 1);
```

Output should be like:

important

[image]

Comment: Thanks! @Faizan Ali I also updated with my solution. Great day for you!